# NLP bag-of-words/TF-IDF for clustering (and classifying) short sentences

Tags: algorithm, nlp, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, tensorflow.js

I want to cluster Javascript objects by one of their string key values (`description`). I already tried multiple solutions and would like some guidance on how to approach the problem.

What I want:
Let's say I have a database of objects. There can be a lot of them (thousands probably, maybe tens of thousands). I need to be able to:

1. Cluster objects by similarity in logical (kinda) groups. Semantic matching would be awesome but for now just string similarity would be enough. After they are clustered I need to assign some `categoryId` to each of them (representing the cluster they belong to).
2. Whenever new objects are added to database I need to classify them to the existing groups/propose new clusters.

I haven't tried solving problem #2 yet, but here is what I have tried with #1.

- **hierarchical clustering with Levenshtein distance (single linkage)** - the problem here was the performance, the results were satisfactory (I used `hierarchical-clustering` library from `npm`) but at around 150 I would have to wait around a minute. Not going to work for thousands.
- **TF-IDF, vectorizing + k-means** - the performance was great. It would go through 5000 objects with ease. But the results were definitively off (might be a bug in my implementation). I used (`natural` library from `npm` to calculate TF-IDFs and `node-kmeans`).
- **Bag-of-Words + k-means** - I am trying to implement this one right now, haven't got any luck yet.

For the #2 I thought of using Naive Bayes (but I haven't given it a try yet).

Any suggestions? It would be fine if the objects would be just clustered. It would be even better if I could extract tags (like from TF-IDF) by which the group was clustered.

Comment: A year an 9 months and no answers. I’m curious if you solved this? as I have a similar problem. Thanks, N

Comment: Could you add a few examples of these java objects with their key-value pairs? This sounds quite doable, but an example would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Using tensorflow, it is possible to create a deep learning model that once trained can serve to predict the class of incoming words.

let's suppose that this is the dataset:

```js
let data = [{description: 'just something', label: '1'}, {description: 'something else', label: '2'}]
```

The first thing to do in text classification is to encode the text as tensor. Many algorithms can be used provided they lead to a good accuracy given the domain of interest. In particular, there is the [universal-sentence encoder](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/universal-sentence-encoder) that will convert each sentence in a 1D tensor of size 512.

```js
const useModel = await use.load()
let features = data.map(d => useModel.embed(d.description))
features = tf.stack(features) // create a 2d tensor from the array of 1d tensor
let labels = tf.oneHot([0, 1], 2) // encode it as oneHot
// more details on labels encoding in this answer 
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59127861/how-may-i-define-my-own-labels-in-tensorflow-js/59128300#59128300
```

The second thing would be to create a model for the classification. Though FCNN can be used, for NLP processing, LSTM or bidirectionnal LSTM are mostly used since the cells will keep the context of the data into account when forwarding the outputs to others layers. Here is an example of such model

```js
const model = tf.sequential({
    layers: [
        tf.layers.lstm({ inputShape: [1, 512], units: 16, activation: "relu", returnSequences: true }),
        tf.layers.lstm({ units: 16, activation: "relu", returnSequences: true }),
        tf.layers.lstm({ units: 16, activation: "relu", returnSequences: false }),
        tf.layers.dense({ units: numberOfCategories, activation: "softmax" }),
    ]
}) // in this example of the numberOfCategories is 2
```

The inputShape of `[n, 512]` is for indicating that the model will be fed with `n` sentence(s) at a time. If the number of sentences is variable, the inputShape will be `[null, 512]`.

The model will be trained

```js
model.compile({
    optimizer: "adam",
    loss: "categoricalCrossentropy",
    metrics: ["accuracy"]
})
model.fit(features, labels, {
    epochs: number,// as needed to have a good accuracy
    callbacks: {
        onBatchEnd(batch, logs) {
            console.log(logs.acc)
        }
    }
})
```

After the model has been trained, for each incoming word, there will be a prediction. But the incoming word would need to be convert first to a tensor a described above.

```js
let prediction = model.predict( await useModel.embed('newWord').reshape([1, 1, -1])).argMax([-1])
prediction.print() // will print the index of the label
```

---

If the training data is not yet labelled ( meaning that the object does not have a label property), the data should be clustered. There is not yet clustering algorithms in tensorflow.js. 
For text clustering, we will first need to create tokens. `use` package has a tokenizer; there is also the package `natural`. After tokenizing, `node-kmeans` can be used to labelizing the dataset. From this step, the first approach can be used.

Another approach might be to use the sentences tokenized to train the model. But since all the sentences do not have the same shape, it will require adding a padding using `tf.pad`