# How may I define my own labels in tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have a three dimensional data say `x,y,z` of any sensor. I'm creating `tensor`of these values like `tf.tensor3d([[[x1], [y1], [z1]], [[x2], [y2], [z3]], ....... so on])` . But I have just two labels that are not numeric values like `[standing , sitting]`. I want to assign a single `label` to the combination of three values of `x,y,z`. How may I train my `model` in `tensorflow.js` using my own labels ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is to create an index of the label.

ES2019

```
const labelArray = ["standing", "sitting"]
const mapIndexLabel = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries({...labelArray}).map(([a, b]) => [b, +a])) // {standing: 0, sitting: 1}
```

The label tensor should be a onehot encoding. Here is an example of how to create it.

```
|features   | labels   |
|-----------|----------|
| feature0  | standing |
| feature1  | sitting  |
| feature1  | sitting  |
```

The array of labels index should be [0, 1, 1] (the indexes are taken from the object above). The label tensor is a onehot encoding of the indexes

```
labelsTensor = tf.onehot([0, 1, 1], numberOfUniqueLabels) // numberOfUniqueLabels = 2 in this case
```

Then after the model can be trained by `model.fit(featuresTensor, labelsTensor)`

Comment: I need more explanation...should I create the table like this to define features and labels?

Comment: The table is just there to give you an explanation of how to create the onehot encoding. In the question you are creating, x,y,z combination as your feature that are 3d tensor. If you need more information, consider closing this thread by accepting the answer and ask a new one adding what else you want to know